# Android Test Storage Mock

Tags: android, unit-testing, mocking, tdd, storage

My application use Storage, but for testing I want to **substitute** it with mock object or smth like that. Is that possible in Android? If yes, could you please provide a link with example how to do it?
Thanks!

Comment: explain "Storage" and "mock object", the question isn't quite clear

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object
http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_android.html#MockObjectClasses

Comment: i know what data storage means, its not clear what you want to do.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337505/mocking-library-framework-that-works-best-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a mocking framework to do this. Check out [this question and the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337505/mocking-library-framework-that-works-best-in-android) for a list of mocking frameworks that work nicely with Android. I personally recommend Mockito, which recently got supported by Android.

Now the question is what to mock. You could try to mock the data storage mechanisms directly, but I would recommend wrapping the data storage in another layer of abstraction. This will give you a clean seam to inject a mock when testing. This design also gives you more flexibility in general (for example, you can change the specific kind of data storage without effecting the business logic of your app).

Let me know if this is the kind of information you are looking for.