# is there a way to test a public method in an Android Service?

Tags: java, android, testing, junit

I got a service listening GCM messages and parsing JSONs around. Eventually (depending on the message content), it writes to SharedPreferences, so it needs `getApplicationContext()`.

If I do a test on the service "as a regular object" (create Service, then execute the method) the `getApplicationContext()` ends up in null when running the test

If I use ServiceTestCase

```
    public void testHandleAuth() {

               // MyClass is tested
               Intent intent=new Intent("com.duniap.ptp.GcmIntentService");
               this.startService(intent);
               GcmIntentService tester = new GcmIntentService();
               // a dummy json encoded in base64
               dummyAuth64="eyJkZXZpY2UiOnsiaWQiOjU2LCJzZWNyZXQiOiJGc3VCcWZsdVFcL2l5bit5TlZadW5uZz09In0sImFjdGlvbiI6ImF1dGhvcml6ZSJ9";
               byte[] bytes = Base64.decode(dummyAuth64, Base64.DEFAULT);
               String dummyAuth = new String(bytes);
               tester.handleGCMmessage(dummyAuth);
                   //null pointer, if I debug I trace it to getApplicationContext() within this method

    }
```

I still get the same null exception

Comment: Where you are using `Context`?

Answer (score 0):

A common way to deal with situations like this is to use a mocking framework in which you effectively simulate the context that your method-under-test interacts with.  So you might mock the `getApplicationContext()` to return a mock context object that is sufficient to use with `SharedContext`.

General references:

- [Unit tests with Mockito - Tutorial - Vogella](http://www.vogella.com/articles/Mockito/article.html)
- [Mockito on Android step-by-step](http://paulbutcher.com/2012/05/15/mockito-on-android-step-by-step/)
- [Mocking library/framework that works best in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337505/mocking-library-framework-that-works-best-in-android)